# How to get a class of a method?

Tags: python, function, class, python-decorators

I created a decorator for a method in my class, but inside the decorator, I need to get the class of the method. How can I do that?

Here is the code of what I am trying to do:

---

```py
def my_decorator(method):
    a = # The class of "method"
    print(a)  # <class '__main__.MyClass'>

class MyClass:
    @my_decorator
    def my_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Comment: class name or object?

Comment: You can't, it doesn't even exist yet. Literally - the `MyClass` class object isn't created until after the entire class scope has executed. Also, note that `my_method` is just a function here. It doesn't know that it's inside of `MyClass`. It doesn't become a method until someone tries to access it from an instance and the descriptor protocol kicks in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix the decorator... you get the reference of the class as the first argument passed to the `__wrapper`. To get the parameter identifier you can use a *code* object and then use it as the key of `locals`.

Notice that this method is sensible on the signature of the decorator. In this case the last `[0]` is needed only because the first argument is `*args`,a `tuple`, and the first entry is needed.

```
def my_decorator(method):
    def __wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        cls = locals()[__wrapper.__code__.co_varnames[0]][0]

        print(type(cls))
        print(hasattr(cls, method.__name__))
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return __wrapper


class MyClass:
    @my_decorator
    def my_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


MyClass().my_method()
```

Output

```
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
True
```

Comment: It works, Thank you. I was just thinking of another way for my code but it looks like it's no longer needed.